# How to identify where exception is being caught?

Tags: java

I've tests where based on some condition, I skip execution in `@BeforeClass` itself like -

```
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeClass() {
        super.beforeClass();
        if (someCondition) {
                //do something
            } else {
                throw new SkipException(
                        "THESE TESTS ARE NOT INTENDED TO EXECUTE: ");
            }       
       }
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        // do something
    }
```

But when I run tests, skipExecution statement is executed still execution goes in method annotated with `@BeforeMethod` and code under it is executed which results my tests in failure instead of skip status.

This issue does not reproduce if I try it out of our automation framework and reproduces only when I try it out with my framework code. Looks somewhere, the exception I'm throwing, is being caught. Actually in my code, I'm not catching it anywhere. I went all the way up to parent classes, still I cannot see exception being caught.

Is there any way using Java APIs with which I can identify where the exception is caught?

Comment: Use some debugger to find out? Side note, is that junit tests, if so, maybe you should take a look at [`Assume`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html)

Comment: With debugger when throw exception statement is executed, control directly goes to `@BeforeMethod` and which does not help to see which catches the exception. And I'm using TestNG.

Comment: Use step by step or some exception breakpoint